# How to install IoncubeLoader on MacOS 10.13

Tags: php, macos, apache, ioncube, macos-high-sierra

I can not get the IoncubeLoader running on my MacOS 10.13.
First I tried - as recommended - to install via loader-wizard. This fails with the error message:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'errors' in
>   /Users/johndoe/Sites/ioncube/loader-wizard.php on line 1252
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array in
>   /Users/johndoe/Sites/ioncube/loader-wizard.php:1252 Stack
>   trace: #0 /Users/johndoe/Sites/ioncube/loader-wizard.php(1294):
>   scan_inis_for_loader() #1
>   /Users/johndoe/Sites/ioncube/loader-wizard.php(3291):
>   find_loader(false) #2
>   /Users/johndoe/Sites/ioncube/loader-wizard.php(3085):
>   ini_loader_errors() #3
>   /Users/johndoe/Sites/ioncube/loader-wizard.php(2908):
>   loader_not_installed() #4
>   /Users/johndoe/Sites/ioncube/loader-wizard.php(2712):
>   default_page() #5
>   /Users/johndoe/Sites/ioncube/loader-wizard.php(115): run() #6
>   {main} thrown in /Users/johndoe/Sites/ioncube/loader-wizard.php
>   on line 1252

Then I tried to copy it manually to the extension folder; this fails because of the missing rights (although I use the admin account):

> $ sudo cp ioncube/ioncube_loader_dar_7.1.so
>   /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/
>
> $ cp: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/ioncube_loader_dar_7.1.so:
>   Operation not permitted

Next I installed the IoncubeLoader via homebrew. This seems to have worked at first glance:

> $ brew search ioncube
>
> ==> Searching local taps...
>
> homebrew/php/php71-ioncubeloader ✔

... but `php -v` doesn't show any installed IoncubeLoader extension, neither does `phpinfo()`.

What more can I do to get Ioncube Loader running? Is there a reference to the homebrew installed loader missing? I am thankful for every hint!

Comment: Seems to me that IonCube is generating these errors, so I would assume it is loaded and working. Maybe its the code its trying to decode thats the problem. Maybe its a version issue

Comment: If you mean the erros thrown by loader-wizard.php: this is the install wizard of IoncubeLoader. I doubt it is loaded because it´s not listed by phpinfo.

Answer (score 0):

I just used another way to solve the problem in my case. I am using MacOS High Sierra 10.13

I created a folder under the `sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/my_extensions`

Then I moved the ioncube extensions downloaded from [ioncube.com](http://ioncube.com)

I copied the downloaded ioncube extensions to the new folder I created like so

```
sudo cp /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Desktop/ioncube/* /etc/apache2/my_extensions
```

I had already extracted the compressed ioncube package to a folder called ioncube on my Desktop.

After that, I restarted apache using `sudo apachectl restart`

Then my ioncube issue was solved. Let me know if this helps.